# youtube-dl can't execute PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get youtube-dl to call a little PowerShell script I made that converts downloaded audio to mp3 while at the same time normalizing it so all songs I download are about the same volume. The problem is that apperently the way `youtube-dl` is trying to execute the it blocks it:

```
PS > youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec "powershell D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 {}" https
://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8v_4O44sfjM
[youtube] 8v_4O44sfjM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 8v_4O44sfjM: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Destination: Christina Perri - Jar of Hearts [Official Music Video]-8v_4O44sfjM.webm
[download] 100% of 4.20MiB in 00:00
[exec] Executing command: powershell D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "Christina Perri - Jar of Hearts [Official Music Video]-8v_4O44sfjM.webm"
D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 : File D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 Christina Perri - Jar of Hearts ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
ERROR: Command returned error code 1
PS > Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Calling the script from powershell directly works as expected:

```
PS > D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "Christina Perri - Jar of Hearts [Official Music Video]
-8v_4O44sfjM.webm"
```

How can I make youtube-dl call my PowerShell script?

Comment: You have a security exception. Your error message tells you what to do. Go to https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170 and follow the instructions.

Comment: First time I went there I overlooked the switch for powershell.exe with `-ExecutionPolicy` as you can see above I already set the execution policy for the system to RemoteSigned and thought that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSinged` to the command as follows:

`PS > youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec "powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShel\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 {}" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8v_4O44sfjM`

I'm still not sure what scope I would need to give that to in order to not have to do that but it works so that's all I want.